# Google BigQuery API PHP Credential

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I want to implement Google BigQuery API so I can execute query from my PHP code in BigQuery.

First I have installed the client library by following command:

```
composer require google/cloud
```

Second I have installed the Google Cloud SDK by following command:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

Then I run this command to create the credential:

```
gcloud beta auth application-default login
```

All the process is success and after run credential request I get the following message:

```
Credentials saved to file: 

[/home/some/my/dir/application_default_credentials.json]

These credentials will be used by any library that requests
Application Default Credentials.
```

Then I want to run this code on PHP:

```
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = 'PROJECT ID';

# Instantiates a client
$bigquery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);

# The name for the new dataset
$datasetName = 'my_new_dataset';

# Creates the new dataset
$dataset = $bigquery->createDataset($datasetName);

echo 'Dataset ' . $dataset->id() . ' created.';
```

But unfortunately I got following message error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Exception\ServiceException' with message 'Could not load the default credentials
```

So my question is: whats wrong and what must I do?

Thank you

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default credentials are provided by the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), versions 2.0.0 and newer. To use them, call useApplicationDefaultCredentials:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
```

Then, use the credentials to access an API service as follows:

```
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books']);
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau');
```

I am suggesting checking out the link I gave it has much more options and we recommend using `service accounts`.

Comment: hi @Pentium10 thanks for your reply, i have try to add $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials(); but i got this return: Fatal error: Class 'Google_Client' not found?

Comment: make sure you run the correct version of the library `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` the github has plenty of examples