# BigQuery PHP simple query example

Tags: php, google-bigquery

Can someone provide a simple example showing how to run a simple query using BigQuery (using the latest client library files) and PHP (Would like to see how the credentials are provided, what all client library files to be used and how to query and provide other details)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library has lots of example and also the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396683/google-bigquery-api-php-credential) has some answers. You can also check out the other questions on the [php+google bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery+php) tag combo.

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: have seen those examples. What I was looking at is just using the php client libraries for google bigquery to fetch the values and provide credentials. I am looking at a way where I can implement without using the google cloud sdk(without providing the credentials as an environment variables and setting them in the code itself).

Comment: Simply say you cannot. Only if you want to write a full library to talk with Google Services, I doubt that's your goal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413717/bigquery-php-examples , the second answer here is implelemented without the google cloud sdk with just the client libraries if im not wrong. But thats again an older version of the client library. So i just wanted an example with the newer version

Comment: No, that's the same just an API from 3 years ago. There are no two things here, cloud sdk and client library is the same. That's old and not compatible with `composer`. You should always go with the newest version of the library. I can't understand why you are looking to find a different way. Everyone uses the above library why you want to go different. You won't find examples if you go different and will be hard.

Comment: ok guess my understanding was wrong, so based on the second answer i just need to include the autoload.php from the client library alone ?and after providing the credentials i can query from the bigquery ?

Comment: Yes, read about autoloaders from PHP to understand why it works so magically.

Comment: Thanks @Pentium10, it was really helpful. I was really misunderstanding the concepts.

Comment: can you give a code snippet showing how to query bigquery like sql ? because we are using setAuthConfig function right, so I wonder how should we pass in the project_id when we are running a query($jobs->query($project_id, $query))