# How to write a sql like query using PHP to get data from BigQuery

Tags: php, google-bigquery

Can someone give me an example where BigQuery can be accessed through php with sql like queries using the current client libraries?

In the new library credentials is given as a json and few other changes are there compared to the older version, and I don't understand how to run the query. So it would be great if some one can provide me a example code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bigquery + PHP examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413717/bigquery-php-examples)

Comment: @Alex nope, $jobs->query($project_id, $query); because in the new library i don't think we need to give project_id separately because credentials is passed on as a json

Comment: Which client libraries are you using?  Have you tried to write any code, and if so, can you share it (and how it fails)? The following question might help with your auth problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396683/google-bigquery-api-php-credential

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question. But I've found [this source code](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#complete_source_code) really helpful in getting started. and it's the official docs. I noticed that this is the only page where they mention how to construct a query from A to Z.

The relevant part of the code:

```php
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);

$query = <<<ENDSQL
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
    CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
  view_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%'
ORDER BY view_count DESC
LIMIT 10;
ENDSQL;

$queryJobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query);
$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery($queryJobConfig);

if ($queryResults->isComplete()) {
    $rows = $queryResults->rows();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        printf('url: %s, %s views' . PHP_EOL, $row['url'], $row['view_count']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $bigQuery = $this->getBigQuery();

    $tableName = $bigQuery->constructTableName('example');

    $query = $bigQuery->client->queryConfig("
        select distinct id from {$tableName}
    ");

    $queryJobConfig = $this->bigQuery->client->query($query);
    $this->$bigQuery->client->runQuery($queryJobConfig);
```

Comment: hi and welcome to SO, ty for contributing. You may consider to make the [tour] and for this answer maybe improve it with some explanations. Also have a look here: [answer]